# PHPStorm References to properties seems wrong

Tags: symfony, service, dependency-injection

*Updated question Title*
Sorry if the title of this question is a little off, I'm really not sure how to phrase it.

I'm trying to create a service that will pull data from a json feed and persist/flush it to my database via doctrine.

After much searching/reading/trial and error I've managed to get my service registered:

```
services:
    fantasyapi:
        class:        FantasyDataAPI\Client
        arguments:    ["%fantasyapi.key%"]
    data_manager:
      class: FantasyPro\DataBundle\DataManager\StadiumParser
      arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager', '@fantasyapi', ::DataBundle.Entity.Stadium]
```

I'm using php storm with the symfony2 plugin.

If i use:

```
$repo = $this->em->getRepository('DataBundle:Stadium');
```

PHP storm reports it as an undefined function.

However if i use

```
$repo = $this->em->em->getRepository('DataBundle:Stadium');
```

php storm does not report it as undefined.

I think i'm doing something wrong as using `->em->em->getRepository` does not feel right.

Am i instantiating the service correctly and if so why do i have to duplicate the reference to the function?

heres the full code of my service:

```
<?php

namespace FantasyPro\DataBundle\DataManager;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use FantasyDataAPI\Client;
use FantasyPro\DataBundle\Entity\Stadium;

class StadiumParser {

    private $em;
    private $client;
    private $stadium;
    /**
     * @param EntityManager $em
     * @param Client        $client
     * @param Stadium       $stadium
     */
    public function __constuct(EntityManager $em, Client $client, Stadium $stadium ) {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->client = $client;
        $this->stadium = $stadium;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public Function parseData(){

        $stadiumData = $this->client->client->Stadiums();

        //get the entity manager

        $repo = $this->em->em->getRepository('DataBundle:Stadium');

        $log = array();

        foreach ($stadiumData as $stadium) {
            // Get the current stadium in the list
            $criteria = array( 'stadiumID' => $stadium['StadiumID'] );
            $currentStadium = $repo-->FindOneBy( $criteria );

            if ( ! $currentStadium) {
                $currentStadium = new Stadium(); //no stadium with the StadiumID exists so create a new stadium

                $logData = [
                    'action'   => 'Added Stadium',
                    'itemID'   => $stadium['StadiumID'],
                    'itemName' => $stadium['Name']
                ];
                $log[] = $logData;
            } else {
                $logData = [
                    'action'   => 'Updated '.$logTitle,
                    'itemID'   => $stadium['PlayerID'],
                    'itemName' => $stadium['Name']
                ];
                $log[] = $logData;
            }
            $currentStadium->setStadiumID( $stadium['StadiumID'] );
            $currentStadium->setName( $stadium['Name'] );
            $currentStadium->setCity( $stadium['City'] );
            $currentStadium->setState( $stadium['State'] );
            $currentStadium->setCountry( $stadium['Country'] );
            $currentStadium->setCapacity( $stadium['Capacity'] );
            $currentStadium->setPlayingSurface( $stadium['PlayingSurface'] );
            $this->em->em->persist( $currentStadium );
        }
        $this->em->em->flush();
        return $log;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your code working? Is the question only about PHPStorm report?

Comment: Thats a good question!! I've set-up a controller which calls the service and then outputs the returned '$log' via twig, not getting any data, i'll dig deeper and check some stuff out.

Comment: Good call it seems I am getting an error when i call `$stadiumData = $this->client->Stadiums();` Call to a member function Stadiums() on a non-object

Comment: *Call to a member function Stadiums() on a non-object* When is `$this->client` declared?

Comment: i'm doing a `var_dump($this)`  for some reason thedependencies are not registering  correctly: `object(FantasyPro\DataBundle\DataManager\StadiumParser)[5133]
  private 'em' => null
  private 'client' => null
  private 'stadium' => null`
the `__construct` is where the properties are declared

Comment: will start another question for this as its not really anything to do with the original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can document the type of each member of your class:

```
<?php

namespace FantasyPro\DataBundle\DataManager;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use FantasyDataAPI\Client;
use FantasyPro\DataBundle\Entity\Stadium;

class StadiumParser
{ 
    /** @var EntityManager em */
    private $em;
    /** @var Client client */
    private $client;
    /** @var Stadium stadium */
    private $stadium;
    /* ... */
```

For some reason PHPStorm didn't recognized the classes when I only used the class name so I had to put the full namespace, e.g.:

```
    /* ... */
    /** @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager em */
    private $em;
    /* ... */
```

Comment: works like a dream i can now omit the extra ->em and PHPStorm Recognises it